# Clarification on FFT

Tags: algorithm, fft, matrix-multiplication

I know there is something wrong with the following reasoning but I'm not sure what it is.

The FFT:

1. given two polynomials

   `A = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n`

   and

   `B = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + ... + b_n x^n`

   you can compute the coefficients of the product

   `AB = \sum _k = 0 ^ 2n ( \sum _ j = 0 ^ k (a_j b_{k-j}))x^k`

   in `O(n log n )` time.
2. So given two vectors `(a_0, ..., a_n)` and `(b_0, ..., b_n)` we can calculate 
     the vector `v_i = \sum j = 0 ^ k ( a_j b_{k-j})` in `O(n log n)` time (by embedding the vectors in zeros.)
3. Given the above, we should be able to calculate the dot product of `A =(a_0, ..., a_n)` and `B =(b_0, ..., b_n)` which is `A.B = \sum_j=0 ^ n a_j b_j` in `O(n log n)` time by preprocessing one of the vectors say `B` to be `B' = (b_n, b_{n-1}, ..., b_1, b_0)` then computing the convolution as in 2. in `O(n log n)` time.

If the above reasoning is correct, then that means we can implement Matrix Multiplication of two `nxn` matrices in `O(n^2 log n )` time by computing the dot product in `O(n log n)` time `O(n)` times.

However, the best run-time for matrix multiplication we know is about `O(n^2.4)` so this seems unlikely to be true, which probably means of of the steps 1,2, or 3 is incorrect.

Comment: what is the run-time of step (3) conversion from B to B'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `n^2` entries in the product, not `n` and so this algorithm would be `O(n^2 * n * log n) = O(n^3 log n)`.

And the best algorithm for computing dot products is `O(n)`, not `O(n log n)`. That's why the naive algorithm for matrix multiplication is `O(n^3)`. (It's `n^2` dot products that can be done in `O(n)` time).

Comment: @gmatt: You shouldn't. Most people don't even reach a point in their life where they are studying the FFT. Just consider it a stumbling block on your path towards enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why it is an achievement that in step 3 you can calculate the dot product in O(n log n) time as it is well known that dot product can be calculated in O(n) time? Also step 2 looks like linear time instead of O(n log n) step?

Also the conclusion about O(n^2 log n) does not follow logically. You can't take the dot product O(n) times resulting in the AB matrix---as far as I know you have to take O(n^2) dot products, leading to (per your analysis) O(n^3 log n) which is inferior to standard O(n^3). This is because of your strange O(n log n) dot product result.